# Use variable declared inside function outside of it

Tags: php

In db.php:

```
function connect() {
    // vars declared
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
}
```

In another file.php:

```
require_once('db.php');
connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("...");
```

How do I use `$conn` outside of the function? All of the answers online refer to the inverse of this. I tried `global` but didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Learn how to **return** values: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: Ummm.  `return $conn;` perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just return it from function and assign to variable.

```
function connect() {
    // vars declared
    return new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
}

require_once('db.php');
$conn = connect();
$stmt = $conn->prepare("...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use 'static' keyword like this:

```
function connect() {
    static $conn;
    if (is_null($conn)) {
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    }
    return $conn;
}
```

Have a look in here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it ouside and access it globally

```
$conn;
function connect() {
    // vars declared
    global $conn;
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
}
```

Comment: While this works, it is considered bad practice. I just wanted to add this for the OP is obviously learning PHP and should avoid to start bad habbits ;)